# Max Length of a Capture Group?

Tags: notepad++

I have a list and forget the right regex to do that.

Example:

```
33463262@3_nr:**fe325252** <<< 8 char 
754754723_rr@:**241321**   <<< 6 char
32523651@61_ff:**78901**   <<< 5 char
```

How to capture only 6 - 25 char after delimiter `:` and delete all line with 5 char

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing 3 Regex Find/Replace passes over the file.

**First Pass** - removes everything apart from the part after the delimiter that you're interested in.

Find:

```
.*?:\*\*(.*)\*\*\s*
```

Replace:

```
$1\r\n
```

**Second Pass** - removes any results with < 6 characters

Find:

```
^.{0,5}$\r\n
```

Replace:

```
*a literal blank string*
```

**Third Pass** - Removes everything with >25 characters

Find:

```
^.{26,}$\r\n
```

Replace:

```
*a literal blank string*
```

After all that, you should be left with just the parts you are interested in.